# I am using Webdriver IO version 5 and need to hover over an element , pause to see the over then click the element

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, cucumber, webdriver-io, gherkin

I am using Webdriver IO version 5 and need to hover over an element , pause to see the **hover** then **click** the element

I tried  **browser.moveToObject(_page.element);**    that pass but I dont see it hovering
I tried  **browser.$(_page.element).moveTo();**   that pass but I dont see it hovering
I tried  **browser.$(_page.element).moveTo( 30, 30 )**   that pass but I dont see it hovering
The docs to me are confusing and I need  to have this working this week!

I forgot to mention this is for DESKTOP on chrome browser

step file

Then(/^I hover over the account tile should change to a hand$/,  function () {
_page = getPage("account details");

```
// _page.transHoverAccount.isDisplayed();
browser.pause(3000);
   
//  browser.$(_page.transHoverAccount).moveTo();    
//   browser.$(_page.transHoverAccount).moveTo( 30, 30 ) 
browser.moveToObject(_page.transHoverAccount);
browser.buttonDown(button);
```

});

Any suggestions?

Comment: I forgot to mention this is for DESKTOP on chrome browser

Comment: for hover effect i used moveTo As well in Chrome browser that works fine.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Scrolls to the element when the element is resolved, then after e.g. 500ms it hovers over it? Currently there is no way to know when the scrolling animation is finished, but 500ms should do.

```
async function hover(element) {
    await element.then(async e => {
        await scrollTo(e);
        setTimout(async()=> { await e.moveTo(); }, 500);
    });
}
```